# BlowFish File ENcryption java.security.InvalidKeyException(Java Eclipse)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

I'm trying to encrypt and then decrypt back a file in Java. I'm using Eclipse IDE. 
The program seems to work fine except that the timer is not working as expected.
I'm using two timers to calculate the encryption and decryption time respectively. 
The decryption time in milliseconds shows 0. Eclipse says:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at AES.<init>(AES.java:133)
    at AES.action(AES.java:311)
    at java.awt.Component.handleEvent(Component.java:6543)
    at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Component.java:4956)
    at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Component.java:4966)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4676)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:647)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:645)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:644)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I'm hereby posting my entire code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

public class AES extends java.applet.Applet {
    Label encry = new Label("Choose Algorithm:   ");
    Choice textAlignment = new Choice();
    TextField TextFieldName = new TextField("", 10);
    TextField TextFieldName2 = new TextField("", 10);

    Image I;
    Label label;
    Label label2;
    private static JFileChooser fc;

    // for AES
    Cipher ecipher;
    Cipher dcipher;

    // for BlowFish
    private static String cipher_key = "Blowfish";  
    private static Cipher cipher;  
    private static KeyGenerator k_generator;  
    private static SecretKey secret_key; 

    private long startTime = 0;
    private long stopTime = 0;
    private boolean running = false;

    public void start() {
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.running = true;
    }


    public void stop() {
        this.stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.running = false;
    }

  //elaspsed time in milliseconds
    public long getElapsedTime() {
        long elapsed;
        if (running) {
             elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        }
        else {
            elapsed = (stopTime - startTime);
        }
        return elapsed;
    }    

    private long startTime2 = 0;
    private long stopTime2 = 0;
    private boolean running2 = false;

    public void start2() {
        this.startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.running2 = true;
    }


    public void stop2() {
        this.stopTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.running2 = false;
    }

  //elaspsed time in milliseconds
    public long getElapsedTime2() {
        long elapsed;
        if (running2) {
             elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2);
        }
        else {
            elapsed = (stopTime2 - startTime2);
        }
        return elapsed;
    }    


    public AES(SecretKey key)
    {
        // Create an 8-byte initialization vector
        byte[] iv = new byte[]
        {
            0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f
        };

        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        try
        {
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

            // CBC requires an initialization vector
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Buffer used to transport the bytes from one stream to another
        static byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        public void encrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        {
            try
            {
                // Bytes written to out will be encrypted
                out = new CipherOutputStream(out, ecipher);

                // Read in the cleartext bytes and write to out to encrypt
                int numRead = 0;
                while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
                {
                    out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
                }
                out.close();
            }
            catch (java.io.IOException e)
            {
            }
        }

        public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        {
            try
            {
                // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
                in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);

                // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
                int numRead = 0;
                while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
                {
                    out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
                }
                out.close();
            }
            catch (java.io.IOException e)
            {
            }
        }

        // for BlowFish encryption
        public void encrypt_data(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException
        {
            //initialize the cipher  for decryption  
               cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret_key);  

            // Bytes written to out will be encrypted
                out = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher);

                // Read in the cleartext bytes and write to out to encrypt
                int numRead = 0;
                while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
                {
                    out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
                }
                out.close();
        }

        //for BlowFish decryption
         public void decrypt_data(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws InvalidKeyException,  IOException {

             // initialize the cipher once again
              cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret_key);      

                // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
                in = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);


                int numRead = 0;
                while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
                {
                    out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
                }
                out.close();
         }



         public AES() {
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                //simpleMethod();
         } 

    public void init() {

                I=getImage(getCodeBase(),"lock.png");
                add(encry);
                label = new Label("Encryption Time ", Label.RIGHT);
                label2 = new Label("Decryption Time ", Label.RIGHT);

        //Add 4 different options to it:
                textAlignment.add("AES");
                textAlignment.add("BlowFish");
                textAlignment.add("PBE");

        //Then add the drop down list to the screen
                add(textAlignment);
                add(label);
                add(TextFieldName);
                add(label2);
                add(TextFieldName2);

        }


        //AES button caused the event
        public boolean action(Event event, Object object) {
             if (event.target == textAlignment) {
                  String selection = textAlignment.getSelectedItem();


                      if (fc == null) {
                            fc = new JFileChooser(".");
                        }
                        // Show it.
                        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
                        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 


                                  if (selection.equals("AES")){
                                       AES s1 = new AES();

                             s1.start(); // timer start
                            KeyGenerator kgen;
                            try {
                                kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

                                kgen.init(128);
                                SecretKey key           =   kgen.generateKey();

                                // Create encrypter/decrypter class
                                // Create encrypter/decrypter class
                                AES encrypter = new AES(key);

                                    try {
                                        encrypter.encrypt(new FileInputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath()),new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/encrypted"));
                                    s1.stop(); // timer stops

                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                       AES s2 = new AES();
                                    // Decrypt
                                    try {
                                        s2.start2(); // timer starts
                                        encrypter.decrypt(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/encrypted"),new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/decrypted"));
                                        s2.stop2(); // timer stops

                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    TextFieldName.setText(Long.toString(s1.getElapsedTime())); 
                                    TextFieldName2.setText(Long.toString(s2.getElapsedTime2())); }

                             catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }               
                    }
    }
                             if (selection.equals("BlowFish")){
                                   AES s1 = new AES();
                                   AES s2 = new AES();

                                     AES encryption = new AES(secret_key);


                                     s1.start(); // timer start
                                   //Generate encryption key based on codecypherkey code word  
                                   try {
                                    k_generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(cipher_key);
                                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }  

                                   //Create a secret key  
                                   secret_key = k_generator.generateKey();  


                                   //Create Cipher based on the previous encryption key code  
                                   try {
                                    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipher_key);
                                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } 

                                try {
                                    encryption.encrypt_data(new FileInputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath()),new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/encrypted"));
                                    s1.stop(); // timer stops
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {
                                       s2.start();
                                    encryption.decrypt_data(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/encrypted"),new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/decrypted"));
                                        s2.stop();

                                        TextFieldName.setText(Long.toString(s1.getElapsedTime())); 
                                        TextFieldName2.setText(Long.toString(s2.getElapsedTime2())); 

                                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                }




                             }

            return running;
            }


        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
        g.drawImage(I,10,10,this);
        }}
```

Thank You for the patience.

Comment: We can't help you unless you share your code. Please write a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem which we can copy/paste/execute and fix. (A.k.a an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: I don't think this counts as a SSCCE. Why are you confusing AES and Blowfish? Please first refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Blowfish Cipher instance to perform Blowfish encryption, not a Cipher instance for AES. The String in getInstance() if Cipher is incorrect. Furthermore you need to make sure that your secret_key is not null during the initialization of the Cipher.

Comment: I've posted my code. Could you be more specific as to where I've messed up. Sorry I'm kind of a beginner.

Comment: To be honest, I think this requires the correct use of a debugger and careful review of the code over a specific question on stackoverflow, dear user. Start with renaming your methods (why is AES in there?), and replacing the default `e.printStackTrace()` (the stupid default inserted by most IDE's with `throw new IllegalStateException(e)`.

Comment: AES s1 = new AES(); // AES is the class name  could you please point out where am I supposed to replace AES with blowfish?

Comment: The question is about blowfish, but the exception is within an AES instantiated Cipher class receiving `null` instead of a key. As I don't have direct access to your code, there is very little I can do to help you here.

Comment: I've posted my entire code. I hope that it makes sense to you now. Thank You for your time.